# how to identify the touched map marker

Tags: android, dictionary, marker

I have populated a list that consists of geopoints. Now all the markers are visible , but when I touch on a marker i should be able to show details regarding that marker as a baloon or pop up, How do i do it.
And along with that the popup/baloon should show the distance between my location and the marker.
Thanks guys

Comment: Hi you can try this code along with demo so you can get idea and solution
[Marker click on map](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons) tapEvent. also this will help you [Tap Event](http://android-coding.blogspot.in/2011/08/detect-touch-on-marker-in-mapview.html)

Answer (score 0):

Override the `onTap()` method in your custom class that you extend from `ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem>`.

```
@Override
protected boolean onTap(int index) {
Toast.makeText(context,
 "Touch on marker: \n" + overlayItemList.get(index).getTitle(),
 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

return true;
}
```

`overlayItemList` is an `ArrayList<OverlayItem>` .

Comment: it is right but like i mentioned , i am a beginner, so it would have helped it a little more clear.